# UWP ComboBox in ListView to edit table

Tags: listview, combobox, uwp

I am a complete greenhorn when it comes about developing UWP C# apps. However, I intend to set up a small project out of interest.

Currently I'm struggling with setting up a table based on an sqlite db. My specific problem is that I would like to edit one column of the table using a Combobox.

To illustrate my problem I've created a small sample to explain the issue I'm struggling with:

My databinding uses a custom ListView and is working as expected with an ObservableCollection.

The Sample class and the set up of the ObservableCollection is all in Mainpage.cs as follows:

```css
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Car> Cars;
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Cars = new ObservableCollection<Car>();
            Cars.Add(new Car { Brand = "BMW", Colour = { "red", "yellow" } });
            Cars.Add(new Car { Brand = "Mercedes", Colour = { "blue", "yellow" } });
            Cars.Add(new Car { Brand = "Scoda", Colour = { "green", "pruple" } });
        }

        private void MyComboBox_Loaded(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var myComboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
            myComboBox.ItemsSource = Cars;
        }
    }
    public class Car
    {
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public List<string> Colour { get; set; }

        public Car()
        {
            Colour = new List<string>();
        }

    }
```

MyDatabinding for the ListView in MainPage.xaml looks as follows:

```css
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!--header of table-->
        <Grid Background="{ThemeResource GridHeaderBackgroundBrush}"  Margin="40,40,40,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="Brand" 
                       Grid.Column="0" 
                       Style="{StaticResource GridHeadingTextBlockStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Colour" 
                       Grid.Column="1" 
                       Style="{StaticResource GridHeadingTextBlockStyle}"/>
        </Grid>
        <controls:AlternatingRowListView
             Margin="40,0,40,0"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind Cars}"
            OddRowBackground="{ThemeResource GridOddRowBackgroundBrush}" EvenRowBackground="{ThemeResource GridEvenRowBackgroundBrush}"
   ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle}"
   ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
   Grid.Row="1"
            x:Name="myListView">
            <controls:AlternatingRowListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Car">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Brand}" Grid.Column="0" />
                        <ComboBox
                            x:Name="MyComboBox"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Loaded="MyComboBox_Loaded"
                            SelectedValuePath="Colour"
                            DisplayMemberPath="Colour">
                        </ComboBox>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:AlternatingRowListView.ItemTemplate>
        </controls:AlternatingRowListView>
    </Grid>
```

FYI: Please note that I do the binding for the ItemsSource for the Combobox in the Load event as I didn't figure out a different solution. I'm not sure if there is a way to inherit the ItemsSource form the upper data template of the listview.

The executed UI looks as follows: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cc0fW.png)

My problem ist that the values of the Colour are not displayed corretly. Due to whatever reason I just get System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.String].

I would be very happy if someone could give me a hint...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is in the binding of the ComboBox. You need to add the following binding in XAML and remove the Loaded event handler.

```
<ComboBox
    x:Name="MyComboBox"
    Grid.Column="1"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind Colour}"
    SelectedItem="{x:Bind CurrentColour, Mode=TwoWay}" >
</ComboBox>
```

This works because Colour is a list of strings, so they display correctly. If it were a complex object, you could use the DisplayMemberPath to get to a particular display string.

You were binding your ComboBox in code to Cars (the wrong object) and then using the display path, but that only got you to a list of strings, not the colors themselves.

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you were after. I assume you will want to next save the selected color in the ComboBox, so you will need to flesh out your Car class to include the ColourList and SelectedColour.

Comment: Thanks. This works. Do you know how I can set selectedindex in xaml?

Comment: Cool, can you accept my answer if that worked for you?
You need another property on Car for CurrentColour. Then bind the ComboBox.SelectedItem to it: SelectedItem="{x:Bind CurrentColour, Mode=TwoWay}".

Comment: Very helpful again ;)

Comment: @Paul glad that worked for you too. Can you please accept the answer if that solved your problem? Thanks.

Comment: @Paul, if you don't know how to accept an answer, could please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).  Accept an   answer that answers your question well.